# Is there a way to reliably search for command line execution in Wireshark?

Tags: wireshark, sniffing

Let's suppose I wish to inspect the Packet Bytes section and search for inbound shell command execution--specifically, the "`dir`" command on a Windows machine.  From a remote attacker's CLI, I'll assume it looks something like this:

`C:\Windows\System32>dir`

Suppose I decide one way to do this is to search for "`>dir`" within the content. Well, I've examined sample pcap files in Wireshark and noticed that rarely does the incoming traffic appear to the human eye as cleanly as this. Instead, I see something like:

```
.......P .|/u~+..
..P...G. ..dir..
Volume i n drive
C has no  label..
. Volume  Serial
```

This would basically break my method... there's no "`>`" character preceding the "`dir`" command.  Without this search constraint, I'm at risk of picking up all kinds of false positives, such as:

`C:\MyDocuments\Indirect...
C:\MyDocuments\MyDirtyPix...`  (gotta have some humor here ;)

Is this a problem I can overcome?  Any suggestions?

Comment: Not a suggestion, but an observation. The text `C:\Windows\System32>` is not typed by the user, it is the prompt emitted by the `cmd` shell. The default prompt happens to be `$P$G` and `$G` causes a `>` to be displayed. The prompt can be changed, try `prompt=.` for example. See [prompt](http://ss64.com/nt/prompt.html) for more information.

Comment: Excellent points, David... thank you.  Permit me to think aloud here--so then I take it that in a reverse shell scenario, it's the victim machine that sends the prompt string, so this would only ever be found in outbound packets.  Just because the C2 host from which an attacker sends a command displays a prompt, that doesn't mean that both the prompt and the command are there to be found in the same inbound packet... you'd only see the command.   Correct?

Comment: That sounds correct to me ;)

Comment: What kind of CLI are you using that you can even view things in wireshark?  Is this psexec, telnet, or what?  Doesn't everyone use an encrypted channel for any kind of remote access these days?

Comment: Should, yes.  And I'm aware that increasingly some form of encryption or obfuscation will be involved  Though let's say an intruder simply tries to hide their traffic by sending through a common port (http/https are more reliably allowed), and no encryption is used.  Where SSL/TLS is relied on, in some cases a company might perhaps take advantage of MITM decryption for deep packet inspection. All this is important, but none of it matters if I don't first understand the subtleties of what happens (or, rather, how things happen) at the uppermost layers--need to know what to look for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no simple search you could in Wire Shark to find specific commands like that. The reason is that users may insert sequences of bytes that correspond to a command without actually sending it all at once. For example `di^Hir`, where `^H` is a backspace, will be interpreted as `dir`, as would `dr←i`, where `←` is the left-arrow escape sequence. They could make it even more complicated, but the point is-- you simply don't have an easy way of finding even three simple characters in order over the wire. Correct, but complicated methods, would probably include hooking into system calls to see which folders/drives/etc are accessed, and so on.